# Send email once not every time post updated

Tags: php, wordpress, email, message

I'm using "[Front End PM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/)" plugin and i have this snippet below for sending message to the post author when his post is published, it's working fine but still sending messages every time the post is updated! How can i stopped that?

Another point is how to send the same message to all registered users?

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage', 10, 2 );

function fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage( $ID, $post ){

    if ( ! function_exists( 'fep_send_message' ) )
    return;

    $message = [];

    $message['message_to_id'] = $post->post_author; // Post author ID. 
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID ); 
    $message['message_title'] = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message['message_content'] = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.', $name, $title );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'This is an automatic message, to let you know your post is published, and qualified for our quality standard!' );
    $override = array('post_author' => 1);//change with message sender id  


    // Send message
    fep_send_message( $message, $override );  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Method :

```
 add_action( 'publish_post', 'fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage', 10, 2 );

    function fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage( $ID, $post ){

        if ( ! function_exists( 'fep_send_message' ) )
        return;


    //Check Send
    $send_email = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fep_send_email', true );
    if ( ! empty( $send_email ) ) return;


        $message = [];

        $message['message_to_id'] = $post->post_author; // Post author ID. 
        $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $permalink = get_permalink( $ID ); 
        $message['message_title'] = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
        $message['message_content'] = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.', $name, $title );
        $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
        $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'This is an automatic message, to let you know your post is published, and qualified for our quality standard!' );
        $override = array('post_author' => 1);//change with message sender id  

    //Set Post Meta
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fep_send_email', '1' );

        // Send message
        fep_send_message( $message, $override );  

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehrshad for your answer, it working Thanks so much, but how can i check if the post is already published before?

Comment: And what about the second point, to send the message to all registered users?

Comment: Meta is created only when the post is created, so the existence of meta means a post published. for the second time, you can add new value, for example, 2.If you do not understand, I'll give you the code.

Comment: Now I understand thanks bro, Is there any way to notice all users as the same way we did with `fep_send_message` and for sure excluding the post author cuz we don't need to notice him twice.